# Select only particular pages of a template in AEM if that component exist in that page

Tags: aem, jcr-sql2

I have a template in AEM where I have to select all pages for the template where the component is present in pages.

Current query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [cq:PageContent] AS page
WHERE  ISDESCENDANTNODE(page, '/content')
AND [cq:template]="/conf/we-retail/settings/wcm/templates/experience-page"
```

This returns all pages but I have to return the selective pages.
For example, currently, there are 2 text components present in the template, and one of the text components is unlocked and modified on page P1.
Now that component is created on Page p1.

I have to return that P1 page in the result

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with a join:

```sql
SELECT page.*
FROM [nt:unstructured] AS component
INNER JOIN [cq:PageContent] AS page
ON ISDESCENDANTNODE(component, page)
WHERE component.[sling:resourceType] = 'your/text/node/resource/type/here'
AND ISDESCENDANTNODE(page, '/content')
AND page.[cq:template]="/conf/we-retail/settings/wcm/templates/experience-page"
```

However, this could be a slow query unless you have all the right indexes in place.
Also, it will return duplicate entries for pages that contain multiple instances of this component (I tried using `SELECT DISTINCT` instead but it didn’t help).